# Webpack não atualizando bundle.js

Tags: javascript, html, react, bundle, webpack

Sou novo nessa coisa de React e Webpack, e estou estudando bastante, mas cheguei num problema que não estou encontrando um modo de resolver.

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: './html/js/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/deploy/assets/',
        publicPath: '/deploy/assets/',
        filename: './js/bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        contentBase: './deploy'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread']
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Este é o meu webpack.config.js.

O problema é, que mesmo eu salvando meus arquivos no projeto e o webpack mostrando no console que foi compilado, a tela não mostra minhas mudanças. Já tentei inclusive, ir pelo caminho localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server para ver se minhas mudanças estavam lá, e estavam!

Mesmo elas estando lá, meu HTML não atualiza, me obrigando a rodar ./node-modules/.bin/webpack de novo para funcionar.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Tentou usar webpack -w? Uma dica, se for trabalhar com React, use o Create React App. Daí não precisa perder tempo com nenhuma config, apenas em trabalhar com React.

Comment: Estás a usar o browser com a consola ativa para ele não fazer cache? senão o browser tenta poupar a ligação e não atualiza os ficheiros. Tenta abrir o endereço noutro briwser.

Comment: @dsantoro já tentei utilizar o -w e nada. Estou criando uma aplicação do zero para eu entender como funciona, talvez eu esteja esquecendo de instalar algo, não sei... Está bem estranho

Comment: @Sergio tambem já tentei em outros browsers, nada...

Comment: @GuilhermeLeonardoUtzig agora entendi o que você falou. Você quer usar o hot reload do webpack server. Algo como "start": "webpack && webpack-dev-server --inline --port XXXX" no seu package.json. Mas ainda te sugiro usar o Creat Reatc App

Comment: @dsantoro Tranquilo, vou pesquisar sobre isso. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução é usar o pacote [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html), além de resolver seu problema ele tem uns [recursos bem legais](https://medium.com/@oieduardorabelo/o-que-h%C3%A1-de-novo-no-webpack-dev-server-2-0-56b47cf2b3f0).

Bom, no seu package.json você pode criar um script da seguinte maneira:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --inline --hot"
  }
```

Repare que no final do script `dev` tenho o parâmetro `--hot`, esse é o cara responsável por fazer o *hot deploy* e atualizar o browser toda vez que eu salvo o código.

Após isso é só rodar seu front com `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o BrowserSync.

para instalar `npm i -D browser-sync browser-sync-webpack-plugin`

no seu `webpack.config.js`

`const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
 // ... 
  plugins: [
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3000,
      server: { baseDir: ['public'] }
    })
  ]`

para saber mais acesse [browser-sync-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync-webpack-plugin)

Answer (score -1):

Habilite a funcao para escrever no disco, da seguinte maneira:

```
 devServer:
{
  writeToDisk: true
}
```